# Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UnaryFunction<Observable<any>, Observable<any>>'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs

i am trying to migrate from `rxjs` 5 to 6 but i am having difficulties. when i try this

```
this._connectivity.isOnline().pipe(first()).subscribe((state) => {
  this.syncCheck(user.uid);
});
```

i am getting this error

```
Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UnaryFunction<Observable<any>, Observable<any>>'.
  Types of parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible.
    Type 'import("/home/User/Desktop/projectname/node_modules/rxjs/Observable").Observable<any>' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/User/Desktop/projectname/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable").Observable<a...'.
      Property 'map' is missing in type 'Observable<any>'.
```

Comment: can you show the imports for this code snippet?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found the same error with my code:

```
let source = of([1, 2, 3, 45, 56, 7, 7])
    .pipe(
        filter((x: number) => x % 2 == 0)
    );
```

TS2345: Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction'.

To fix this, remove type from filter function

```
 filter(x => x % 2 == 0)
```

Now you have error

The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', so make sure, that this annoying filter gets correct data type

```
filter(x => Number(x) % 2 == 0) // parse element to number
```

But now code stops work. Finally, to fix this, change of to from, at the beginning.

```
let source = from([1, 2, 3, 45, 56, 7, 7])
    .pipe(
        filter((x: number) => Number(x) % 2 === 0)
    )
```

or

```
let source = of(1, 2, 3, 45, 56, 7, 7)
.pipe(
        filter((x: number) => Number(x) % 2 === 0)
    )
```

So, cause of error was my initial data structure.

I think, that my example can help you with dealing similar problems.

Answer (score 12):

You seem to have a wrong import for the `isOnline()` return type. Make sure that you always import from `rxjs` and never from `rxjs/internal` or even `rxjs/internal/Observable`. (Operators like `first()` must be imported from `rxjs/operators`)

Comment: YES!  Thanks, this answer saved me.  In VSCode I had auto-imported `map()` from the wrong library without realising it.  It's worth checking imports if you're getting type weirdness.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar error using pipe in one of HTTP services method (see example on the bottom). The problem was lack of typing in callback function used in subscribe. In your case, add typing (not the best idea but even `any`) to `state` or remove the parenthesis:

**Solution 1:**

```
this._connectivity.isOnline()
  .pipe(first()).subscribe((state: any) => {
    this.syncCheck(user.uid);
});
```

**Solution 2:**

```
this._connectivity.isOnline()
  .pipe(first()).subscribe(state => {
    this.syncCheck(user.uid);
});
```

Coming back to my case I've used pipe to log log the data. It required to set two possible types to the observable, then typing callback function was possible:

```
  public getPrice(): Observable<string | PriceDTO> {
    return this.http.get<PriceDTO>(`api/price)
      .pipe(
        tap((data: PriceDTO) => console.log('PRICE: ', data)),
        catchError((val: Error) => of(`I caught: ${val}`))
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have such issue, first scan wasn't working, 
so I 
changed

```
  .pipe(scan((count ) => count + 1, 0))...
```

To

```
  .pipe(scan((count:any ) => count + 1, 0))
```

Then the problem also was that the Rxjs was installed also at the parent folder of this app. So removing this,I believe have fix the problem.

Using [npm-check](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check) package is good idea for cleaning problem either global and local level of npm packages.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem with the code below

```
mockDetalhes(): Observable<IResponseGenericPage>{
    return of(detalhesMock)
}
```

The issue was resolved by adding the type inside the **of** operator, like this:

```
mockDetalhes(): Observable<IResponseGenericPage>{
    return of(<IResponseGenericPage>detalhesMock)
}
```