# Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<any, any>'

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm using `rxjs/opterators` to map `valueChanges` of `FormControl` into `Observable`, like:

```
options$: Observable<any[]>;

ngOnInit() {
    // update options$ 
    this.options$ = this.inputCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(null),
      map(text => this.filter(text, value))
    )
}

filter(text: string, list: any[]): any[] {
    // set text in lowerCase for comparison
    text = text.substr(index).trim().toLowerCase();
    // filter list based on text
    return list.filter(item => item.trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(text) !== -1);
}
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<any, any>'.
Types of parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible.
```

I search for solution, I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51646369/argument-of-type-monotypeoperatorfunctionany-is-not-assignable-to-parameter/55668969) but it didn't work to me, cause I already import operators from `rxjs/operators`, like:

```
import { startWith, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

What is the problem? and how can I fix it?

**UPDATE:**

I get this error for first operator, `startWith`, I tried to remove it but then I got it on `map`!

Comment: Could you share a stackblitz for this?

Comment: Could you share other imports besides `startWith` and `map` operators, because this error could be thrown because of wrong `Observable` import

Comment: @nimeresam, an Observable with an array of any? Definitely probably need more code here.